# @import bootstrap-sass not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, compass-sass, bower

I've set up a new npm/bower/grunt/sass/compass project and now I'm trying to get bootstrap in there too. For the life of me though, I cannot seem to get my scss file to recognize it. I've got compass and sass working, but any way I try to `@import bootstrap`, I'm getting this error:

```
error sass/style.scss (Line 2: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
Load paths:
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/webnamehere2.0/sass
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.6/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.6/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
Compass::SpriteImporter)
```

I'm trying to load up 'bootstrap-sass' through bower. Is this saying I have to go the Ruby way? I've tried:

```
@import 'bootstrap'
@import 'bootstrap-sass
@import '../bootstrap'
@import 'bootstrap-sass-official'
```

and changing the style.scss file to style.css.scss.

Here's an image of my projects directories, if that helps anyone with anything:

[image]

Can someone please let me know how I can get this project to see Bootstrap?

Comment: ok i solved my issue in case anyone else is having it. When you use "@import bootstrap", its referring to the boostrap.scss file. I moved that file into my own 'sass' folder, then changed the paths of all the files in the 'bootstrap.scss' file. This youtube video does a great job explaining. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34yWSY0qnVY

Comment: You should use a relative path like `../bower_components/bootstrap/more_folders/file.sass`. Packages installed by bower should be use as-is and left alone so they can continue to be managed by bower in the future (update / install / prune / etc).

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer and mark it as completed.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to import Bootstrap using Sass depends on the version and package you are using. Here are a few common scenarios:

**Using Bootstrap v3 with the bootstrap-sass package:**

```
@import 'bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
```

**Using Bootstrap v4 or later with the bootstrap package:**

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

**Using a customized or local Bootstrap installation relative to your project:**

```
@import '../path/to/bootstrap';
```

Make sure you have the appropriate Bootstrap package installed and configured in your project. Also, ensure that your Sass file is
correctly configured and processed by the Sass compiler or build
system you are using.

Answer (score -4):

Answer from **@nickg**

When you use `@import bootstrap`, its referring to the `boostrap.scss` file.

I moved that file into my own `sass` folder, then changed the paths of all the files in the `bootstrap.scss` file.

This youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34yWSY0qnVY) does a great job explaining.